# Is it possible to use a "confirm your email" options in google forms?

Tags: google-forms

What I mean is during or after form is complete, send an email to the user to respond so he could confirm the address is a real one.

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an answer, but I've used Google Forms a few times and I don't think I've ever seen that option. You might want to try a different platform (such as Survey Monkey, although I don't know if they offer that feature either) or develop something to do that follow-up for you.

Answer (score 0):

Google Forms does this automatically, you just need to open the form you want to modify go to settings and select the first option that is something like "allow only one answer". 
 Bear in mind that this will require that your respondants to login into the google services, and if they don't have a google account they will need to create one.

Comment: That's true, but I wanted to be able to do it with any email address

Comment: well, they can create a google account with their e-mail, but they cannot do it without a google account